# Apache doesn't serve home dir

Tags: permissions, apache-2.2, home-directory

I want to serve a home dir from apache but it's going to a permission denied error.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 with Apache2. The error in the log file is:

```
[Tue Jun 21 15:55:34 2011] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/pedro/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable.
```

In an older installation of ubuntu that I had, I was getting the same error and I had just enabled mod_userdir for apache and all worked fine, but know even if I enable this mod it doesn't work.

The dir permissions that I tried to serve:

```
drwxr-xr-x  8 pedro pedro 4096 2011-06-20 20:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 pedro pedro 4096 2011-06-20 19:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x 13 pedro pedro 4096 2011-06-20 19:39 app
drwxr-xr-x  6 pedro pedro 4096 2011-06-20 19:39 cake
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pedro pedro 6526 2011-06-20 19:39 gerenciador_eventos.sql
drwxr-xr-x  8 pedro pedro 4096 2011-06-20 19:39 .git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pedro pedro   87 2011-06-20 19:39 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pedro pedro  295 2011-06-20 19:39 .htaccess
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pedro pedro 1850 2011-06-20 19:39 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  4 pedro pedro 4096 2011-06-20 19:39 players
drwxr-xr-x  2 pedro pedro 4096 2011-06-20 19:39 plugins
-rw-r--r--  1 pedro pedro 3330 2011-06-20 19:39 relatorio.backup
drwxr-xr-x  4 pedro pedro 4096 2011-06-20 19:39 vendors
```

The virtualhost config that I am using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gerenciador_eventos

    DocumentRoot /home/pedro/dev/k2tv/gerenciador_eventos

</VirtualHost>
```

It is weird becouse when I was using the Ubuntu 10.10 it was working perfectly, unless I am missing some confirmation, but I don't think so.

Comment: Need ls -ld of / and /home and /home/pedro. Also check audit.log to see if SELinux is unhappy with your choice of userdir.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure Apache has `+x` (execute) permissions on *all* parent directories: `/`, `/home`, `/home/pedro` and so on.

If standard Unix permissions are used (i.e. no ACLs), this command will help:

```
namei -l /home/pedro/dev/k2tv/gerenciador_eventos
```

Comment: Never heard of the `namei` command before. Thanks for the tip!